# Using Android Emulator on a Mac, OPTION and CMD buttons are disabled

Tags: macos, android-emulator

Well, I installed Android Studio on a Mac OS X El Capitan. Well, the only way I know to write the character `@` is pressing <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>. It turns out that when I open the Android Emulator, I can't write it because the <kbd>OPTION</kbd> seems to be disabled.

Trying to copy and paste the character does not work too, because <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> does not paste anything on Android Emulator (*sigh*). I think that <kbd>CMD</kbd> is disabled too?

Do you know how can I configure the Emulator on Mac to be able to use the <kbd>OPTION</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>?

**EDIT:** I disabled the keyboard input on the Emulator, and I'm using the software keyboard provided by the device. It's not ideal, but, works. Anyway, it would great be able to use the keyboard without any problems.

Comment: Why dont you write @ using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>?

Comment: My computer has a keyboard with a Spanish layout. Shift + 2 writes quotes ("). Option + 2 writes @... Thinking in your advice, I could change my keyboard layout to English to be able to use Shift + 2. Anyway, it would be only a workaround, because it would be a pain too, change layouts all the time